# select all the highest money making movies from each studio IN mysql TABLE

Tags: mysql

I have a table which has a studio, title, and worldwide column in my MYSQL table. I want to select all the highest money making movies from each studio. How can I achieve this? Please help me. Thank You

***Edit***

I have the following code now but it doesn't work properly

```
SELECT studio, max(CAST(worldwide AS INT)* 1000000), title FROM top_movies GROUP BY studio;
```

Comment: why isnt working properly? and why you multiply by 1 million?  Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/)

Comment: what is the datatype of worldwide ? why you cast worldwide in int and multiply by 1000000 ?

Comment: Worldwide is text. It has been multiplied because all values were written as 886.92 instead of 886920000

Comment: what is the output come from ?

Comment: why you use `worldwide` if you have `total_money` column?

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT studio_name, movie_name, total_money
FROM top_movies 
JOIN 
    (
      SELECT studio, max(total_money) tmoney
      FROM top_movies 
      GROUP BY studio
    ) b
   ON top_movies.studio = b.studio
  AND top_movies.total_money = b.tmoney
```

Comment: It is returning the same results as the first try. The reason I know this is because the most worldwide value is of Avatar by Fox which is on my table but it shows some other movie instead. Same for Titanic and Parmount

Comment: This is the right process. The problem is you dont explain where the money is. First you say there is a `total_money` column but then use a `worldide` column. So what is it? The process is simple you first found it what is the biggest value and then join back to the table so you get all the columns from that row.

Comment: `total_money` was the wrong name. It is called`worldwide`

Comment: Then again I sugest you read the links I provide. As part of the question you have to include db schema `(fieldnames and data types)` then some sample data and expected result. If you have an error you also include it as part of the question, not in the comments where other cant miss it. Also, `doesnt work` doesnt really help, you need to explain what is wrong. Finally the problem looks like the conversion. just remove the `group by` and cast every value. Check if you are getting the correct value. Post that info and we continue from there

Answer (score -1):

You cast value as a `integer` but as your comment the `worldwide` value is floating value(886.92) so `cast as decimal`. Try This

```
SELECT studio, MAX(CAST(worldwide AS DECIMAL(20,2))* 1000000), title 
FROM top_movies 
GROUP BY studio;
```

OR

```
SELECT studio, MAX(CAST(worldwide AS DECIMAL(20,2)))* 1000000, title 
FROM top_movies 
GROUP BY studio;
```

hope this will give correct result